# PHP Preg_replace: can't get the replace part to work, finding is fine

Tags: php, regex

I don't know how to do the following:

find all instances of `'/\s[2-9]\)/'` and replace the space with a `<br />` tag.
Something as simple as this doesn't work:

```
$preg_num = ' /\s[2-9]\)/';
$preg_fix = "'/<br>/[2-9]\)'";
preg_replace($preg_num,$preg_fix,$notes);
```

What do I need to change the $preg_fix variable to?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Do you get an error message? What does it say? Are you checking for error conditions or error return values? Can't see that, please do handle error return values and please read the manual how actually the function you're using works.

Comment: Can you provide the text (or parts of) of your source and to what it should be replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a lookahead is simpler than a backreference, IMHO.

```
$preg_num = '/\s(?=[2-9]\))/';
$preg_fix = '<br/>';
preg_replace($preg_num,$preg_fix,$notes);
```

This way, you are only replacing the space with the `<br/>`.

Answer (score 2):

The replacement string is not treated as a regex — it is more like a literal string. If you are trying to put whatever digit `[2-9]` that was matched in the original regex into the replacement string, capture the character as a group and use a backreference.

```
$preg_num = '/\s([2-9])\)/';
$preg_fix = "<br />$1)'";
preg_replace($preg_num,$preg_fix,$notes);
```

For more information:

- [`preg_replace`'s `replacement` parameter documentation](http://php.net/preg_replace#refsect1-function.preg-replace-parameters)
- Regular expression grouping: ["Use Round Brackets for Grouping"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)